# Swift 5, Kingfisher - How to guarantee no duplicate images when loading images to Collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, kingfisher

I am currently using Kingfisher library to load thumbnail images for collectionview cells and if it is already recorded in the cache, it would load from the cache. Seldomly some images are loaded for wrong cell which leads to duplicate images in the collectionview. When I try to scroll down and then dismiss/dequeue again, images are then correctly placed. This issue is not present if I do not use functionality of retrieving image from the cache also.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SimpleThumbnailView", for: indexPath) as! ThumbnailsCollectionViewCell
        cell.thumbnailImage.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        cell.prepareForReuse()
        if indexPath.row < thumbnails.count {
            let urlString = thumbnails[indexPath.row].thumbnail ?? ""
            ImageCache.default.retrieveImageInDiskCache(forKey: urlString) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let image):
                    if image == nil {
                        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: urlString)
                                cell.thumbnailImage.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: UIImage(named: "DefaultImage"), options: [])
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.thumbnailImage.image = image
                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            
            cell.titleLabel.text = thumbnails[indexPath.row].title
            cell.authorLabel.text = StringBuilder.authorLikes(author: thumbnails[indexPath.row].writer, likes: thumbnails[indexPath.row].likeCount)
            cell.articleId = thumbnails[indexPath.row].articleId
            cell.authorId = thumbnails[indexPath.row].writer
            if cell.articleId != -1 {
                cell.removePlaceHolder()
            }
        } else {
            thumbnailCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
        return cell
    }
```

and this is my prepareForReuse()

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        thumbnailImage.kf.cancelDownloadTask()
        thumbnailImage.image = UIImage(named: "DefaultImage")
    }
```

I also tried using cancelDownloadTask() function about anywhere I could think of but this didn't worked either. Could someone have an idea how to solve this problem?

- this issue is also not present if all images are loaded from the cache disk

Comment: Firstly you don't really need the following line
`thumbnailCollectionView.reloadData()`
Secondly you don't need to call `cell.prepareForReuse()` as it automatically calls
Your code seems good to me, you can try to `cancelDownloadTask()` after assigning default image in `prepareForReuse()`

Comment: You shouldn't load the from cache, KingFisher should do it itself. The cancel download too. If I remember correctly, it through the associated object that it works, adding a "id" to the image (the URL), and that it avoid your issue with wrong images at the wrong place.

Comment: So I'd recommend to only use `kf.setImage(...)`, but use the completion handler method, and check `RetrieveImageResult.cacheType`, I guess it should show for some that it's coming from the cache.

Comment: @Larme So I shouldn't be using the ImageCache.default.retrieveImageInDiskCache, let me check that out.

Comment: @Larme Thank you, I guess I was using cache all this time even before using ImageCache.default.retrieveImageInDiskCache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the reuse system used in `UICollectionView`/`UITableView` is important, and that's why you dequeue cells.

When a cell disappear, it goes on the "available cells pool" in memory.
When you need to show a cell, it's check if there is an available cell in the previously mentioned pool, if not it creates one.
That's for optimisation. Why? Let's imagine that you have 10k cells to show, but only can show 5 at the same time on the screen, let's add 1 more cell (when scrolling, you see the bottom only of the first one, and the top of the new one). Do you think it'd be efficient to create 10k cells? Not, let's just create 6, and reuse them. That's the whole optimization behind reusing cells (in Android SDK, it's "Recycling", for Recycle View, the concept being the same).
But when the cells goes out of screen, it's put in the pool as "such", with all the customization it had before (like label values, colors, subview, etc.). There it will call `prepareForReuse()` to put it in a "blank" state (do not call it yourself). It's not needed to override `prepareForReuse()` if you have for instance only one `UILabel` and in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` you change its value each time (it'd be `label.text = nil` in `prepareForReuse()` directly changed in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` into `label.text = "myValue"`, which is extra work not necessary.

Once you understood this, the current issue with your code is this one:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SimpleThumbnailView", for: indexPath) as! ThumbnailsCollectionViewCell
    //First Async call (I guess it's async)
    ImageCache.default.retrieveImageInDiskCache(forKey: urlString) { result in
        //Second async call
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            cell.thumbnailImage.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

You use two async call (but one is enough to create the issue), so when the closure is called and when you want to set the value, the cell might already have been reused for another `indexPath`. Hence the issue you get having images at wrong index paths cells when scrolling.

Now, you can say that `setImage(with url:)` from KingFisher/Alamofire+Image/SDWebImage and other libs are using a "hidden" closure too and they don't have the issue. It's because they use `associated_object`, which let them to add an extra value to an object (the `UIImageView`). That extra value is an id (the URL of the image), so when they want to set the image, they check if the imageView associated id is still the correct one, if not, the cell has already been reused.
That's a simplification of what's done.

So in your case, you could add extra value to the cell, and check if it's really the same inside the closure, but in fact it's not needed, because you're overthinking the issue with KingFisher.

Depending on how you use KingFisher (there are extra parameters : force refresh etc), but by default it will cache itself the images, and check in its cache if it's there or not and avoid a web call.

Here, I'd suggest remove all of the cache check code (since it's already done by the lib):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SimpleThumbnailView", for: indexPath) as! ThumbnailsCollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row < thumbnails.count {
        let urlString = thumbnails[indexPath.row].thumbnail ?? ""
        cell.thumbnailImage.kf.setImage(with: urlString, placeholder: UIImage(named: "DefaultImage"), options: []) //Might need a if let url here
        cell.titleLabel.text = thumbnails[indexPath.row].title
        cell.authorLabel.text = StringBuilder.authorLikes(author: thumbnails[indexPath.row].writer, likes: thumbnails[indexPath.row].likeCount)
        cell.articleId = thumbnails[indexPath.row].articleId
        cell.authorId = thumbnails[indexPath.row].writer
        if cell.articleId != -1 {
            cell.removePlaceHolder()
        }
    return cell
}
```

Now, if you want to check for yourself, you can put breakpoint inside the lib, of use the `setImage()` with the completion parameter. I didn't test it, but I guess the answer from where is coming the image, cache or not might be in the `RetrieveImageResult` value.

```
setImage(with: urlString, placeholder: UIImage(named: "DefaultImage"), options: [], completionHandler: { result in 
    switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case success(let imageResult):
            //check imageResult, maybe cacheType, source, etc.
    }
}
```

Another issue you had was reloading of the whole collectionView.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with Kingfisher but would expect it does its own caching. However, your problem is a classic bug with asynchronous code in `cellForItemAt`.

Collection (and table) view cells are reused when scrolling. If you perform any asynchronous work in `cellForItemAt` then there is a chance that by the time the completion handler is called the cell will have already been reused for a different index path. Your code is assuming that the `cell` that is dequeued for a particular item is still being used for that item when the completion handler is called. Depending on timing and how fast you scroll the item you started the asynchronous code for may no longer be on screen or may now be used for a different item.

In the `DispatchQueue.main.async` blocks where you assign the cached or fetched image you need to [ask the collection view](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem) for the cell corresponding to the index path rather than assuming it is still the cell you first dequeued. This will be nil if that item is no longer on screen.

Comment: `This will be nil if that item is no longer on screen`, It's not related to the question and is just a matter of release time.

Comment: Handling the case where the cell for an item is no longer on screen is an important part of using asynchronous code in `cellForItemAt`. The original cell will still be cached by the collection view, ready to be reused later for another item on scroll or reload. It won’t be released/deallocated until the collection view itself is released.